# Is there a way to adjust the interval for the update-status hook?

Tags: juju

Is there a way to set the interval for update-status hook? As per my observations, it runs after every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, sorry. For now, it's hard coded.

Comment: Hmm. Wouldn't that mean you could find it in the source, change it and  and recompile?

Comment: Yeah but then you'd have to maintain your own copy of Juju. I'd like to know more specifics about what @Junaid is trying to do, perhaps there's another way to do what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Nate and Jorge, I get there are other ways to achieve that. Sorry, newbie to juju, so i just posted the question without looking around official sources.

Answer (score 1):

```
juju model-config update-status-hook-interval=60s
```

See https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.4/en/models-config